# Extracting columns from a text file and put into a new text file in a specific format.

Tags: python, vba, excel

I have data in the following format in a text file.  The first row represents a time step.  The first column represents a location and the next four columns represent different values at the location.

```
0.017
    1   0.11    0.40    0.02    0.73
    2   0.86    0.86    0.30    0.25
    3   0.95    0.20    0.50    0.71
    4   0.68    0.93    0.07    0.78
    5   0.65    0.80    0.75    0.46
    6   0.16    0.37    0.89    0.69
    7   0.22    0.50    0.66    0.63
    8   1.00    0.17    0.95    0.65
    9   0.12    0.45    0.56    0.05
    10  0.67    0.73    0.48    0.33
0.034                   
    1   0.19    0.91    0.11    0.69
    .
    .
    .
```

I need to get it to the following format in a new text file.

```
TS 1 0.017
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
0.11
0.86
0.95
0.68
0.65
0.16
0.22
1.00
0.12
0.67
TS 1 0.034
1
.
.
0.19
```

I need to add "TS 1" to the time step in the first row for each time.  I then need to have all of the locations listed in order (1-10 in this case) and then the values from column 2 listed in the same order as the locations just below.

I need this to iterate through multiple time steps until the end of the text file which can be millions of lines long.  I would like this done in either Python or VBA in Excel.  Any ideas on how to start?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import re

SPACE = re.compile(ur'\s+')


def write_rows(f, rows):
    if rows:
        for row in rows:
            f.write(row[0])
            f.write('\n')
        for row in rows:
            f.write(row[1])
            f.write('\n')

with open('in.txt', 'r') as fi:
    with open('out.txt', 'w') as fo:
        rows = []
        for line in fi:
            bits = SPACE.split(line.strip())
            if len(bits) == 1:
                write_rows(fo, rows)
                fo.write('TS 1 ')
                fo.write(bits[0])
                fo.write('\n')
                rows = []
            else:
                rows.append(bits)

        write_rows(fo, rows)
```